# error validation not showing for select element when uniform and validation plugin is used

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am trying to use Inline Form Validation Engine 2.6.1, jQuery plugin with uniform ui jquery plugin. the validation message shows well with input text boxes. but for select (drop down) element the vallidation error message is not showing.

below are links to plugin which I used.

thanks for any help or suggestion in advance

expecting replies as I  need this thing to fixed urgently.

[Validation plugin githhub](https://github.com/posabsolute/small-build-script-with-node)

[validation plugin_doc](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/simple-build-script-to-minify-and-concatenate-files-using-node-js/)

[Uniform ui plugin](http://uniformjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this happens is because Uniform uses a div with overflow hidden to contain all the elements, so basically your error message is there but you can't see it outside the div I just mentioned.

Long story short, search inside Uniform CSS file for the code bellow and comment or delete the overflow line.

```
div.selector {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

Comment: oh thank god, I also had been looking for a solution to this damned things for weeks!

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, all you have to do is override the CSS style for the div.selector.

```
div.selector {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
 overflow: visible;
```

}

Comment: oh thank god, I also had been looking for a solution to this damned things for weeks!